# Rss feed from facebook without logging in

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook page that i'd like to pull the wall posts from and into a personal web page. I cannot figure out how to do this without making users log into facebook. I do not want the user to have to log into facebook in order for my wall posts to show up.

I am using asp.net. Ideally, i'd like to execute code on the server side and log into facebook using my ID on the server and pull my wall posts and display it to the users. However, this doesn't seem to be possible without getting an access token which can't be done programmatically from what I've seen. All code snippets i've seen to log into facebook requires their oauth web form to popup and you have to type in your user name and password, ideally i'd like to hard code my user name and password on the server and the server will log in for me and then fetch the data on my behalf.

Anyone know if this can be accomplished?

Comment: You can do this with access tokens. Here's a similar question and answer: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12902633/how-can-i-show-my-personal-stuff-from-facebook-in-my-website/12903612#12903612

Comment: The link you sent me does not solve my issue. I do not want a long lived access token nor do I want a application token which logs into the user on their behalf. I want to login with my credentials, each time and every time. Can this be done?

Comment: I'm not aware of another way to do what you want.  I'm pretty sure that's it for now.

Comment: Thank you for your time Donn, I'll post here if I find a way or a work around.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this component can authenticate you programmatically: http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/oauth.aspx